# Covariance of a Vector-Valued Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, covariance

I'm reading through Andrew Ng Lecture Notes for CS229 and he makes the statement that, for a random variable $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$,

\begin{align}
Cov(Z) &= E[(Z - E[Z])(Z - E[Z])^{T}]\\
       &= E[ZZ^{T}] - E[Z](E[Z])^{T}
\end{align}

I've started with:
\begin{align}
Cov(Z) &= E[(Z - E[Z])(Z - E[Z])^{T}]\\
       &= E[(ZZ^{T}) - 2(E[Z]Z^T) + E[Z](E[Z])^{T}]
\end{align}

But I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: You can develop the product and use the fact that for all row vectors $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n, xy^\top=yx^\top$.

Comment: Edited to better illustrate where I'm getting stuck

Comment: The first term is already what you want. The third one is deterministic so you can take it out of the expectation. In the second one, $2E[Z]$ is deterministic so you put it as a factor: $E[2(E[Z]Z^\top)]=2E[Z]E[Z^\top]=2E[Z]E[Z]^\top$. Now you can simplify.

Comment: Use linearity to rewrite this as a sum of three terms.  Then notice that $E[Z]$ is a constant vector.

Comment: @charlus when you say deterministic, what do you mean mathematically? (I've never taken a stats class so apologize for silly question)

Comment: And @Peter, can we assume that E[Z] is linear -- I haven't seen that

Comment: Kudos to you for tackling this great courses by Andrew Ng. Don't get discouraged by barriers of entry... By deterministic they simply mean that it is a number ($E[Z]$ is simply the arithmetic mean of $Z$). So if it is seen multiplying a random vector $(Z^\top),$ you can just take it out, as you would with $5x+5y=5(x+y).$

Comment: By linear they just mean that the expectation is a linear operator. That means that the expectation of a sum of variables is the expectation of each one of those variables added up. The mean of the heights of boys and girls together is the same as the mean of the heights of the boys plus the mean of the heights of the girls.

Answer (score 1):

You have (with the middle step added)

$\qquad\begin{align}
\mathsf{Cov}(Z) &= \mathsf E[(Z - \mathsf E[Z])(Z - \mathsf E[Z])^\top]
\\ &= \mathsf E\big[ZZ^\top - Z\,\mathsf E[Z]^\top- \mathsf E[Z]\,Z^\top + \mathsf E[Z]\,\mathsf E[Z]^\top\big] 
\\ &= \mathsf E\big[ZZ^\top - 2\,\mathsf E[Z]\,Z^\top + \mathsf E[Z]\,\mathsf E[Z]^\top\big] &&\text{because }Z\,\mathsf E[Z]^\top=\mathsf E[Z]\,Z^\top
\end{align}$

But for the same reason:

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf{Cov}(Z)&= \mathsf E\big[ZZ^\top - 2\,Z\,\mathsf E[Z]^\top + \mathsf E[Z]\,\mathsf E[Z]^\top\big]  \end{align}$

Then it is just a matter of using Linearity of Expectation

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf{Cov}(Z)&= \mathsf E[ZZ^\top] - 2\,\mathsf E[Z]\,\mathsf E[Z]^\top + \mathsf E[Z]\,\mathsf E[Z]^\top\\&=\mathsf E[ZZ^\top] - \mathsf E[Z]\,\mathsf E[Z]^\top  \end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

Just derive as an extension of the single variable case. Derive Variance(X), where X is a random variable, as a function of E(X), you get E($X^2$) - $(E(X))^2$.
Just extend to the multivariate case, while remembering some of the other hints listed in above comments.